# Plot dotted line in seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

In the plot above, is there a way to plot one of the line types as a dotted line, e.g. plot the 'rest' line as dotted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `linestyles` argument and select [desired type of line](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle) according to matplotlib:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.factorplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, linestyles=[":", "-","-"])
plt.show()
```

[image]